# QGIS 3.2 Raster Histogram frequency axis always locked at 1

Tags: qgis, raster, histogram

Question is pretty much in the title: Whenever I go to layer properties and generate a histogram for a raster the frequency axis of the histogram is capped at 1. So for say a multi-band image I see the pixel values for the multiple bands on the x-axis of the histogram and the frequency of those values on the y-axis. My problem is that the range of the y-axis displayed is from 0-1 which is useless. How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user, please be sure to take the [tour] to learn about this site's focused Q&A format.